I need to share a list between these 2 functions that are being called in different threads
I want to use the list frame_buffer in both functions update_frame and get_stream these 2 fucntions are called in different threads but I am using a lock object so I am stumped by this please help.
import cv2
import time
from flask import Flask, Response
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
import threading
import detect
import queue

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)
frame_lock = threading.Lock()
global frame_buffer
frame_buffer = queue.Queue(maxsize=10)

def update_frame(image):
    """ Update the frame buffer with encoded image data. """
    global frame_buffer
    ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
    if ret:
        frame_lock.acquire()
        if frame_buffer.full():
            frame_buffer.get_nowait()  # Remove oldest frame
        frame_buffer.put(buffer.tobytes())
        print("Frame added to buffer. Current buffer size:", frame_buffer.qsize())
        frame_lock.release()
    else:
        print("WARNING: Frame encoding failed.")
    time.sleep(0.1)  # Limit the rate of frames being added

def get_stream():
    """ Generator function to stream video from the buffer. """
    global frame_buffer
    print("getstream:",frame_buffer.qsize())
    frame_lock.acquire()
    
    frame_data = frame_buffer.get()
    if frame_data != None:
        
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame_data + b'\r\n')
    else:
        print("Buffer empty. Waiting for frames...")
    frame_lock.release()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '''<html>
<head>
    <title>Live Stream</title>
    <script>
        function refreshImage() {
            var img = document.getElementById('stream');
            img.src = '/video_feed?' + new Date().getTime();
        }
        setInterval(refreshImage, 100);  // Refresh every 100 milliseconds
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Live Stream</h1>
    <img id="stream" src="/video_feed" width="640" height="480">
</body>
</html>'''

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(get_stream(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    print('Client connected')
    emit('stream_start', broadcast=True)  # Let clients know that the stream has started

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def handle_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')

def run_web():
    print("Starting Flask server...")
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False, threaded=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cam_thread = threading.Thread(target=detect.runDetect)
    cam_thread.start()  # Start the camera thread to update frames
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False, threaded=True)
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Shutting down...")


I tried many things that were suggested by chatgpt and I couldn't reach a solution. I am trying to stream the yolov5 detection window so what I did was create a function called update_frame that takes as argument an image and call it inside the detect.py of yolov5 in the same script of update_frame I am using flask to create a webpage that has an  that gets updated using that frame I retrieved but for some reason the global variable is not the same in both functions

You mean the variable frame_buffer (which refers to a queue, not a list)? Why do you think it isn't shared? What exactly happens, what should happen?

I print the variable in both functions in one of them frame_buffer is empty and the other contains 10 elements it is a limit I set to 10.

I guess that this problem is somewhere outside of the shown code.

I don't know how to show my whole code base and even if I did I think things can become more complicated. what I need to know is that this is a valid way of sharing a queue variable between 2 threads or should I try pointers ? or the problem is on a whole other level? such as physical access to the memory?

You use the right way to share the queue object. The line global frame_buffer outside of a function on module level is useless but also harmless, by the way.
